# async processing in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a service that implements functionality to return data from sentiment analysis APIs. The client can request results from one or all engines and I want to collate all the data together. I want to process these async and wait for them all to complete before returning the result set. I'm new to async programming and I really cant figure out how to arrange the code and how to implement it syntactically. Here's an EXAMPLE of what I'm TRYING to achieve (I know this doesn't work, but you get the idea; hopefully :-) ):

```
    private ISentimentResponse ProcessRequest(ISentimentRequest request, SentimentEngineServices selectedEngines)
    {
        SentimentResponse response = new SentimentResponse();
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        foreach (SentimentEngineServices engineService in (SentimentEngineServices[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SentimentEngineServices)))
        {
            if (((int)engineService & (int)selectedEngines) > 0)
            {
                ISentimentEngine engine = _engineFactory.GetSentimentEngine(engineService, null);
                Task<ISentimentEngineResult> task = new Task<ISentimentEngineResult>(engine.AnalyseSentimentASync(request));
                taskList.Add(task);
            }
        }
        if (taskList.Count > 0)
        {
            ISentimentEngineResult[] results = Task<ISentimentEngineResult>.WaitAll(taskList);
            foreach (result in results)
                response.Add(results);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

The engine has the following code implementation of engine.AnalyseSentimentASync:

```
    public ISentimentEngineResult AnalyseSentiment(ISentimentRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            MultiLanguageBatchInput sentimentList = SentimentRequestToMicrosoftBatchInput(request, Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguage);
            SentimentBatchResult sentiment = _client.Sentiment(sentimentList);
            KeyPhraseBatchResult keyPhrases = _client.KeyPhrases(sentimentList);
            return MicrosoftBatchResultsToSentimentEngineResult(sentiment, keyPhrases);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogMessage(ex,$"{EngineName} threw an unknown exception: ", LoggingLevel.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }
    public async Task<ISentimentEngineResult> AnalyseSentimentAsync(ISentimentRequest request)
    {
        return AnalyseSentiment(request);
    }
```

What do I need to do and is there any better way to achieve this?

I've looked everywhere for an example but I cant find one that addresses my implementation requirements, or the whole approach is completely wrong!

Thanks all,

Stu.

Comment: You have two options. 1. Does  your `_client` support async versions of methods, for example `_client.KeyPhrasesAsync(...)`? If so, use them. 2. You can run this on thread pool threads by using `Task.Run`.

Comment: Your approach of wrapping `async` around non-async methods will not work well. You have to make all your methods you call asnyc until you have an external event (network, parallel CPU intensive calculations etc.) to wait for (so `AnalyseSentiment` -> `AnalyseSentimentAsync`, `Sentiment` -> `SentiimentAsync`), `KeyPhrases` -> `KeyPhrasesAsync` etc.)

Comment: Ok, I see. So better in this case to run each as a separate thread then? i.e. essentially separate tasks as FCin suggested also? I thought that adding engine.AnalyseSentimentASync(request) to a task, then everything from thereon would be managed by the Task<ISentimentEngineResult>.WaitAll(taskList) call? Wishful thinking?!

Comment: @Stuie_M Does you `_context` have async versions of methods? `MethodNameAsync()`? This is the most important part here.

Comment: You mean _client? Yes it has async methods for both calls _client.SentimentAsync and _Client.KeyPhrasesAsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can convert it to async:

```
public async Task<ISentimentEngineResult> AnalyseSentimentAsync(ISentimentRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        MultiLanguageBatchInput sentimentList = SentimentRequestToMicrosoftBatchInput(request, Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguage);
        SentimentBatchResult sentiment = await _client.SentimentAsync(sentimentList);
        KeyPhraseBatchResult keyPhrases = await _client.KeyPhrasesAsync(sentimentList);
        return MicrosoftBatchResultsToSentimentEngineResult(sentiment, keyPhrases);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogMessage(ex,$"{EngineName} threw an unknown exception: ", LoggingLevel.Error);
        throw;
    }
}

private async Task<ISentimentResponse> ProcessRequestAsync(ISentimentRequest request, SentimentEngineServices selectedEngines)
{
    SentimentResponse response = new SentimentResponse();
    List<Task<ISentimentEngineResult>> taskList = new List<Task<ISentimentEngineResult>>();
    foreach (SentimentEngineServices engineService in (SentimentEngineServices[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SentimentEngineServices)))
    {
        if (((int)engineService & (int)selectedEngines) > 0)
        {
            ISentimentEngine engine = _engineFactory.GetSentimentEngine(engineService, null);
            Task<ISentimentEngineResult> task = engine.AnalyseSentimentASync(request);
            taskList.Add(task);
        }
    }
    if (taskList.Count > 0)
    {
        ISentimentEngineResult[] results = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
        foreach (result in results)
            response.Add(results);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Remember that you have to call it from some kind of event handler. I don't know what framework you are using (wpf, asp.net, windows service, webapi).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here it is:

```
        public ISentimentResponse AnalyseSentiment(ISentimentRequest request, SentimentEngineServices selectedEngines)
        {
            if (selectedEngines == SentimentEngineServices.None) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(selectedEngines));
            ValidateRequest(request);
            return ProcessRequestAsync(request, selectedEngines).Result;
        }
        private async Task<ISentimentResponse> ProcessRequestAsync(ISentimentRequest request, SentimentEngineServices selectedEngines)
        {
            SentimentResponse response = new SentimentResponse();
            List<Task<ISentimentEngineResult>> taskList = new List<Task<ISentimentEngineResult>>();
            foreach (SentimentEngineServices engineService in (SentimentEngineServices[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SentimentEngineServices)))
            {
                if (((int)engineService & (int)selectedEngines) > 0)
                {
                    ISentimentEngine engine = _engineFactory.GetSentimentEngine(engineService, null);
                    Task<ISentimentEngineResult> task = engine.AnalyseSentimentASync(request);
                    taskList.Add(task);
                }
            }
            if (taskList.Count > 0)
            {
                ISentimentEngineResult[] results = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
                foreach (var result in results)
                    response.Add(result);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

And the sentiment interface implementation:

```
 public async Task<ISentimentEngineResult> AnalyseSentiment(ISentimentRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                MultiLanguageBatchInput sentimentList = SentimentRequestToMicrosoftBatchInput(request, Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguage);
                SentimentBatchResult sentiment = await _client.SentimentAsync(sentimentList);
                KeyPhraseBatchResult keyPhrases = await _client.KeyPhrasesAsync(sentimentList);
                return MicrosoftBatchResultsToSentimentEngineResult(sentiment, keyPhrases);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogMessage(ex,$"{EngineName} threw an unknown exception: ", LoggingLevel.Error);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Thanks FCin.